# Reshuffle numpy array based on indices in a second array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
A = np.array([6, 7 ,8 ,9, 0])
B = np.array([5, 3, 2, 4, 1])
```

And would like to reshuffle the first one using the second array. So the first element of A should go to place 5 in the output array. The second element should go to to the third etc. So the output array becomes:

```
C = np.array([0, 8, 7, 9, 6])
```

This is simple using a simply python loop, but I would like to use numpy only. Speed is very important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy allows you to use `B` to index `A`.  You have to subtract 1 from `B`, because indices in numpy arrays begin at 0:

```
In [17]: A = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 0])

In [18]: B = np.array([5, 3, 2, 4, 1])

In [19]: C = A[B-1]

In [20]: C
Out[20]: array([0, 8, 7, 9, 6])
```